# How to Set an array as Tag to any View through layout xml in android

Tags: android, xml, view

I want to bind some extra data with a view. I am using tag in my xml file to add the extra information.

If the data is only String (`android:tag="extra Info"`), i am able to get the extra data by using `getTag()` in code.

But i want to bind multiple data as object to a view, for that i am setting an array as tag.
When i tried to set `android:tag="@array/xyz_array"`, I am still getting a String object instead of an array from `getTag()`.

Can any body tell me, if i am doing something wrong ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do this from XML, XML supports only strings for view tags.

Comment: @Romain Guy: can you elaborate for better understanding of other readers. Do you mean we can do it via code using `setTag()` but not via putting some class attribute in xml directly ?

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can do that if you define tag elements as a child for views. [Define multiple Tag attribute for View in xml layouts](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Tags)

```
<View ...>
     <tag android:id="@+id/mytag"
          android:value="@string/mytag_value" />
 </View>
```