# Editing android:tag in layout XML

Tags: android, android-layout

Official documentation says:

> Supply a tag for this view containing a String, to be retrieved later with View.getTag() or searched for with View.findViewWithTag().

`getTag ()` returns an `Object` which shouldn't be a string exactly. Of course I can set a custom object as a tag in `setTag (Object)` method. But can I do the same thing in layout XML (e.g. assign an enum value to a tag)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Set an array as Tag to any View through layout xml in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100381/how-to-set-an-array-as-tag-to-any-view-through-layout-xml-in-android)

Comment: Maybe, but info about tags in XML is almost impossible to find.

Comment: Not questioning that, but it asks the same question and get's the same answer. Hence it should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Set an array as Tag to any View through layout xml in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100381/how-to-set-an-array-as-tag-to-any-view-through-layout-xml-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something similar was answered in the question and the answer is NO:

[How to Set an array as Tag to any View through layout xml in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100381/how-to-set-an-array-as-tag-to-any-view-through-layout-xml-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

In the layout xml files you got the `android:id`, maybe you could use this instead of `getTag()` cause this attribute can only be set in the javaCode (afaik).

Comment: I use tags for other purposes. E.g. I want to know the value of a selected radio button in `RadioGroup` and it'll be more comfortable to initialize them as values of enum directly in XML.