# Use of android:tag parameter in xml?

Tags: android, xml, tags

I saw a xml layout which has a textView as below

```
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHeaderTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Change password"
            android:tag="@string/regular"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/header_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font30" />
```

I want to know what is `android:tag` property is used for. A detailed answer for be greatly appreciated.

Note - I read that it is used for data binding, but could not follow the context.

Update 1 - (Thanks Blackbelt for the answer)
Usages
1. Could be used for compile time binding of xml elements with the activity. Although android recommends the use of `id`.
2. Could be used for identifying elements for list adapter. For eg, a special case of a list adapter with multiple sort support. Then we could use the `tag` element to identify the desired list item.

I would be glad to know if it could also be used for assigning any other property?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100381/how-to-set-an-array-as-tag-to-any-view-through-layout-xml-in-android

Comment: Read https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:tag

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I want to know what is android:tag property is used for

it is a different way to add associate additional information with the view object itself. In you case your `tag` is a `string`, but it can store complex objects too. For instance the tag could be a model class set and retrieve at runtime using the `setTag()`/`getTag()` pair. The way this information is used is up to the users. Android allows to [findViewWithTag](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag(java.lang.Object)) too. In your case, for instance you could look for the same object using `findViewById(R.id. tvHeaderTitle);` or using      `findViewWithTag(getString(R.string. regular));` . An example of usage is with `ListView` when you have a button part of you item and, upon click you want to know the which item in your dataset is associated with that row. Using the pair `setTag`/`getTag` this thing is easily achievable