# How to make Image Buttons act like Radio buttons

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make Image buttons act like Radio buttons. Let me explain. I have a basic layout containing an Image Button and a TextView, that I load with different images and texts.

**XML layout :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java method :**

```
LinearLayout categoryLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.categories_layout);

        for (int i = 0; i<categories.size(); i++) {
            final String name = categories.get(i).name;
            final int resource = categories.get(i).resource;

            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.choose_category, null);

            final TextView text = v.findViewById(R.id.text_category);
            text.setText(name);

            ImageButton button = v.findViewById(R.id.button_category);
            button.setImageResource(resource);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    selectedCategory = resource;
                    text.setTypeface(text.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                }
            });

            categoryLayout.addView(v);
        }
```

Every time an image is clicked, the text is set bold to indicate which button was clicked. My problem is that I only want one button to be clickable at a time. I thought of, each time a button is clicked, reseting the appearance of all TextView, only leaving the last text that was clicked as bold. However, I don't know how to navigate through all layouts that have been generated.

I hope I was clear, thank you if you can help me !

Comment: try using `tag` attribute see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343138/use-of-androidtag-parameter-in-xml you might need to use some logic

Comment: I would use one single custom `actionListener` for all radio buttons, which listens for a specific action command, like "RADIO_BUTTON_ACTIVE", which the active radio button uses, while all inactive radio buttons have an action command like "RADIO_BUTTON_INACTIVE".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might not be the most efficient way to solve this problem, but it works. Every time the button is clicked, the icon selected is saved. Then, I use `removeAllViews()` method on the RadioGroup, and recreate the views. I just make sure the text below the previously selected icon is set bold.